# How to Calculate the Divergence in Metpy?

Tags: metpy

Would you like to know how the divergence calculation is done in Metpy? We know that in Grads the calculation of divergence is performed by the finite difference method as follows:

```py
pi = 3,14159265359 

dtr = pi / 180 

a = 6,371e6 

dx = a * cos (dtr * lat) * dtr * cdiff (lon, x) 

dy = a * dtr * cdiff (lat, y) 

div = cdiff (u, x) / dx + cdiff (v, y) / dy-v * tan (dtr * lat) / a
```

However, in Metpy I didn't find anything detailed (as it is in the Grads) of how this calculation of divergence is performed.

Answer (score 2):

MetPy's divergence calculation ([`metpy.calc.divergence`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/_modules/metpy/calc/kinematics.html#divergence)) internally uses the 3-point differencing [`first_derivative`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.first_derivative.html#metpy.calc.first_derivative) function to calculate divergence in Cartesian form as

[image]

[As referenced in the MetPy documentation](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.first_derivative.html#metpy.calc.first_derivative), this explicitly handles irregular spacing according to the Bowen and Smith (2005) formulation. However, the final coordinate-correction term which GrADS includes, `v * tan (dtr * lat) / a`, is not included in the current MetPy calculation (this is part of [an open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/893)).

Answer (score 1):

Divergence in MetPy is calculated by using the `first_derivative` function in MetPy, which is center-based, except at the edge points, to add together `dudx` and `dvdy`. If you pass `metpy.calc.divergence` or `metpy.calc.first_derivative` an `Xarray.Dataset` with coordinates/projection information, it will calculate the divergence across the varying grid. Otherwise, you need to provide the grid spacing. See https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/_modules/metpy/calc/kinematics.html#divergence and https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.first_derivative.html#metpy.calc.first_derivative for more information on the divergence function and  coordinate-array handling.

Comment: As of MetPy 0.10.2, [`metpy.calc.divergence`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.divergence.html#metpy.calc.divergence) does not yet pull out required metadata when using xarray; you still have to provide the grid spacings yourself. There is, however, the convenience function [`grid_deltas_from_dataarray`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.grid_deltas_from_dataarray.html#metpy.calc.grid_deltas_from_dataarray) which makes this straightforward.